# ignoring config hostname database

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following database configuration:

```
 # Configure your database
config :phoenix_chat, PhoenixChat.Repo,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "postgres",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool_size: 10
```

I am having issues trying to connect to my postgres, so I decided to debug it with `show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error` and saw this:

```
** (KeyError) key :database not found in: [types: Postgrex.DefaultTypes, repo: PhoenixChat.Repo, port: 5432, hostname: "db", username: "postgres", telemetry_prefix: [:phoenix_chat, :repo], otp_app: :phoenix_chat, timeout: 15000, pool_size: 10, show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true, pool: DBConnection.ConnectionPool]
    (elixir) lib/keyword.ex:389: Keyword.fetch!/2
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:90: Postgrex.Protocol.connect/1
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:66: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
```

How can it be using hostname "db"? I am clearly specifying hostname "localhost" and there isnt any hostname "db" defined anywhere in any of the config files, is it defaulting somewhere?

Comment: Find in _all_ files `"db"`? I doubt there is a default in `Ecto`.

Comment: Is there a chance you're starting the repo explicitly via `PhoenixChat.Repo.start_link(name: ..., hostname: ...)` redefining the hostname? Anyway, I agree with Aleksei - just grep the whole project for `db` and check each suspicious occurrence

Comment: That was it, I was overriding the config on Repo.start_link